# Data factory data flow expressions vs dynamic expressions

Tags: nsregularexpression, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to find the equivalent to doing this in the Wildcard path dataflow expressions. I use this in my data factory dynamic queries

```
@concat(  pipeline().parameters.source,
              '/dirName/year=',
              formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy'),
              '/month=',
              formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'MM'),
              '/day=',
              formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'dd')
          )
```

I thought it would be something like this

```
concat( $source,'/dirName/year=',toTimestamp(currentUTC(), 'YYYY', UTC),
              '/month=',
              toTimestamp(currentUTC(), 'MM', UTC),
              '/day=',
             toTimestamp(currentUTC(), 'dd', UTC)
          )
```

What I'm trying to do is source from a blob path created with UTC date
*example*
blah/year=2021/month=07/day=05/.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something easier as toString(year(currentUTC())) will work easier. Or a string interpolation without concat would also work

"/dirName/year={year(currentUTC())}/month={month(currentUTC())}/day={day(currentUTC())}"

Comment: Thanks 
I actually went with 
concat('dirName/year=',
                  toString(currentUTC(), 'yyyy'),
                  '/month=',toString(currentUTC(), 'MM'),
                  '/day=',toString(currentUTC(), 'dd')
              )

Answer (score 0):

`day` is not a function in Data flow expression builder. 
So, its better to go with:

```
concat('dirName/year=', toString(currentUTC(), 'yyyy'), '/month=',toString(currentUTC(), 'MM'), '/day=',toString(currentUTC(), 'dd') )
```